# How to use <a> & href tag in React-Router

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router, href, passport.js

I need to use an `<a href=""></a>` in React Router in order to use Passport.js in my application for OAuthentication. Whenever I create an anchor tag and click it in React it just goes to a blank page in React Router and I don't even get the callback from my Node server on the backend with all the verification from Google/Facebook/Linkedin

What is a useful way to have an `href` tag in React-Router so that my backend can register it, go through its api flow with the callbacks, and then send it to the right place in React-Router?

The problem is this

[The Problem of using axios.get() for OAuthentication with Passport.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47682987/passport-js-oauth-with-axios-get-call-in-react-redux-cors-policy-with-react-ro)

**EDIT**

In this post they have the same problem that I do and the solution was just a simple href tag, however I have react-router on my application and its possible they did not, also they have no example

[Previous post about Authentication with Passport.js with React front](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44814735/authentication-with-passport-facebook-express-create-react-app-react-rou?noredirect=1#comment82292242_44814735)

**EDIT**

I am moving this project from jQuery focused to React, React-Router and Redux so a majority of my server-side Node code didn't need updating but here is ther part of my routes that handles the OAuth with Passport. I just need my front to reach this, let it do its thing and then send back to me

```
router.get('/linkedin', passport.authenticate('linkedin'),
    function(req, res){
      console.log('nexted')
    }
  );

  router.get('/linkedin/callback', 
      passport.authenticate('linkedin', { failureRedirect: '/index' }),
    function(req, res) {
      console.log('here')
      res.redirect('/professionals');
  });
```

Comment: a blank page in react-router? what are you expecting to see after clicking on that href tag.

Comment: I wish for it to go to the server in a GET request and have it handled and thrown around in that flow so that I may get the appropriate callback and OAuthentication via passport.js. I have edited my post to show common problem but difference is thwy didn't have react router and I do

Comment: react-router doesn't prevent you from doing that. sounds like the route on your server (express?) which handles the oauth link isn't catching or you didn't set it up right. can you post the express setup for the href link and your react application?

Comment: I certainly will

Comment: how are you serving the front end?

Comment: I set up a create-react-app inside my node app as per some tutorials I use axios for my calls but here i get the CORS issue even though I have done multiple things to make sure my app has the appropriate headers

Answer (score 1):

I noticed in the comments that you mention having CORS problems, if I'm right I believe you are using the authorization code grant OAuth flow, I had the same issue with GitHub when I had my SPA and my backend in different servers. If this is the case serve the static files of the SPA through the backend server. If you do this you should put the code below as your last route in order for React Router to work. You can find a repo where I did the same [here](https://github.com/dimkirt/pragma-react-frontend/blob/master/server.js)

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/client/index.html'));
});
```

Note: If you don't want to do this you can use the implicit grant OAuth flow, and make the authentication in the SPA.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion but still no luck. I got a `302` for my http get from my server but it didn't follow the normal passport flow. I think the best route here is to abandon the React-Router and use a regular href tag.....

Comment: Status 302 is used for redirection, when do you get it? I did not understand. Is the `console.log('here')` printed?

Comment: the `console.log` never gets printed. I get the 302 status whenever I try to access the page with axios.get. I think i will just remove ReactRouter from my application or just include it in after the passport portion to allow for login because having social media log in is important to my application

Comment: Have you tested the OAuth flow from Postman or Insomnia? Does it work properly? Only when you try through react it fails? Also do you serve the react files from the same server with the auth routes?